# Create row of most frequent value in each dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, oversampling

**CONTEXT**

I want to create a top row with the most frequent values of each column.

**CURRENT CODE**

```
df = df.loc[df['Gender'] == 'M']
df = df('Gender').count()
```

**DATA SAMPLE**

```
Gender      Eyes      Hair    Height
  M         Brown     Brown    >6ft
  M         Blue      Blonde   <6ft
  M         Brown     Blonde   <6ft
```

**EXPECTED OUTCOME**

```
Gender      Eyes      Hair    Height
  M         Brown     Blonde    <6ft
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `mode`

```
df.mode()
  Gender   Eyes    Hair Height
0      M  Brown  Blonde   <6ft
```

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly what the *mode* function in Pandas does. Assuming your data sample is *df*, you can obtain your expected output using the following line of code

```
df.mode()
```